# Parsing Date in an if-statement and showing only results in stipulated time range

Tags: java, simpledateformat

Currently I'm writing a java program to find out on which day a [*Hammer*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hammer_(candlestick_pattern)) or other [*Candlestick* pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Candlestick_pattern) formed.

The user has to input 2 dates as arguments when executing the program, e.g. *java ReadingTest 2016-09-03 2016-10-31*, and the program will look for Hammer pattern from 2016-09-03 to 2016-10-31.

The code is as follows:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.text.*;

public class ReadingTest
{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException,ParseException
    {
    //Import file to java
    File file = new file("table.csv");

    //Read the file
    Scanner infile = new Scanner(file);

    //Skip the first line in table.csv
    infile.nextLine();

    //Define format of date
    SImpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");

    //Name the variables user enters
    Date start = sdf.parse(args[0]);
    Date end = sdf.parse(args[1]);

    //Create ArrayList for each column of data
    ArrayList<String> date = new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayList<Double> open = new ArrayList<Double>();
    ArrayList<Double> high = new ArrayList<Double>();
    ArrayList<Double> low = new ArrayList<Double>();
    ArrayList<Double> close = new ArrayList<Double>();

    while (infile.hasNext())
    {
        //Tokenize columns by comma
        String[] data = infile.nextLine().split(",");
        //Organize each column of data to one index of data array
        date.add(data[0]);
        open.add(Double.parseDouble(data[1]));
        high.add(Double.parseDouble(data[2]));
        low.add(Double.parseDouble(data[3]));
        close.add(Double.parseDouble(data[4]));
    }
    //Show options and ask user to choose
    System.out.println("1. Hammer");
    System.out.println("2. Three white soldiers");
    System.out.println("3. Bullish kicker");

    //Record user input and execute corresponding code
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    int choice = input.nextInt();

    if (choice == 1)
        for (int i = 0; i < date.size(); i++)
            if (close.get(i) > open.get(i) &&
                close.get(i) > ((high.get(i)) + (low.get(i)))/2 &&
                ((close.get(i) - low.get(i))/2 > (high.get(i) - close.get(i)))
            System.out.println("Pattern found: " + date.get(i));
}
}
```

The code works perfectly till here. However, the output in the last line of code is in the dd/MM/yyyy format and I tried to use sdf.parse(date.get(i)) instead of date.get(i) to show results in yyyy-MM-dd format. Running the code with sdf.parse(date.get(i)) returns the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: 
"25/10/2016" at 
java.text.DateFormat.parse(Unknown source) at ReadingTest.main(ReadingTest.java:59)
```

I also tried to display only dates showing a [Hammer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hammer_(candlestick_pattern)) using:

```
(date.get(i).after(start) && date.get(i).before(end))
```

and results in

```
error: cannot find symbol
symbol: method before(Date)
location: class String
```

And the CSV file looks like this:

```
Date       Open  High  Low  Close  
31/10/2016 58.25 58.65 58.2 58.35
28/10/2016 58.95 59    58.3 58.35
.
.
.
1/8/2016   50.8  51.1 50.75  50.8
```

How the code should be amended to make it work?

Comment: Your code is not compiling due to some basic typo(i.e. the missing bracket at the beginning of the main function). Try to give a proper code sample next time.

Comment: By the way, you are using old date-time classes, now legacy, supplanted by the java.time classes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess what you want is this

```
SimpleDateFormat hammerFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
SimpleDateFormat slashFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
```

so you can parse your date to the `yyyy-MM-dd` representation like this

```
hammerFormat.format(slashFormat.parse(date.get(i))));
```

Full Code

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class ReadingTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, ParseException {
        // Import file to java
        File file = new File("table.csv");

        // Read the file
        Scanner infile = new Scanner(file);

        // Skip the first line in table.csv
        infile.nextLine();

        // Define format of date
        SimpleDateFormat hammerFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
        SimpleDateFormat slashFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");

        // Name the variables user enters
        Date start = hammerFormat.parse(args[0]);
        Date end = hammerFormat.parse(args[1]);

        // Create ArrayList for each column of data
        ArrayList < String > date = new ArrayList < String > ();
        ArrayList < Double > open = new ArrayList < Double > ();
        ArrayList < Double > high = new ArrayList < Double > ();
        ArrayList < Double > low = new ArrayList < Double > ();
        ArrayList < Double > close = new ArrayList < Double > ();

        while (infile.hasNext()) {
            // Tokenize columns by comma
            String[] data = infile.nextLine().split(",");
            // Organize each column of data to one index of data array
            date.add(data[0]);
            open.add(Double.parseDouble(data[1]));
            high.add(Double.parseDouble(data[2]));
            low.add(Double.parseDouble(data[3]));
            close.add(Double.parseDouble(data[4]));
        }
        // Show options and ask user to choose
        System.out.println("1. Hammer");
        System.out.println("2. Three white soldiers");
        System.out.println("3. Bullish kicker");

        // Record user input and execute corresponding code
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        int choice = input.nextInt();

        if (choice == 1)
            for (int i = 0; i < date.size(); i++)
                if (close.get(i) > open.get(i) && close.get(i) > ((high.get(i)) + (low.get(i))) / 2 && ((close.get(i) - low.get(i)) / 2 > (high.get(i) - close.get(i))))
                    System.out.println("Pattern found: " + hammerFormat.format(slashFormat.parse(date.get(i))));
    }
}
```

Edit:

With a .csv file format like this (because in the code it says `.split(",")`)

```
31/10/2016, 58.25, 58.65, 58.20, 58.35
28/10/2016, 58.95, 59.00, 58.30, 58.35
01/08/2016, 50.80, 51.10, 50.75, 50.80
```

It works fine for me. I passed the two arguments `2016-09-03 2016-10-31` when executing the program.

Comment: there is an error saying exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundException: 0 at ReadingTest.main<ReadingTest.java:26> even the ArrayOutOfBounds Exceptiono is added

Comment: @Z_Z you have to pass the two arguments when executing the program. Also see the edit in my answer

Answer (score 2):

The Format in the file has NOT the Format "yyyy-MM-dd", it has the Format "dd/MM/yyyy", so you cannot parse it with your variable sdf. You could define a second date format

```
SImpleDateFormat sdfParse = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
```

and then do parsing with this and formatting with yours:

```
sdf.format(sdfParse.parse(date.get(i)))
```

to hopefully get a better result.

Answer (score 1):

## tl;dr

> Parsing Date

Use only *java.time* classes for date-time work.

```
LocalDate start = LocalDate.parse( "2018-10-27" );  // Parse input string as a date-only value (no time-of-day, no time zone), a `java.time.LocalDate` object.
```

> … in an if-statement and showing only results in stipulated time range

```
if ( 
    ( ! stockDay.getDate().isBefore( start ) )     // A shorter way to ask "is equal to OR later" is "is NOT before". 
    && 
    stockDay.getDate().isBefore( stop )            // Half-Open approach, where beginning is *inclusive* while the ending is *exclusive*.
) { … }
```

Even better, represent your start-stop date range using the `LocalDateRange` class found in *ThreeTen-Extra* library.

```
if ( 
     LocalDateRange.of( start , stop )
                   .contains( LocalDate.parse( "2018-10-27" ) )
) { … }
```

## Details

> How the code should be amended to make it work?

You may be sorry you asked. I went a little nuts with this Answer, being curious about [Candlestick Hammer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hammer_(candlestick_pattern)), and wanting to work more with [Java Streams](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/streams/index.html).

## Fix the date-time handling

You are using troublesome old date-time classes that were supplanted years ago but the *java.time* classes.

Furthermore, you are abusing those legacy classes. You are putting a date-only value in a date-with-time-of-day type. Use `java.time.LocalDate` instead, for a date-only value.

You failed to define a formatting pattern to match your inputs. Your pattern says `"yyyy-MM-dd"` but your inputs are in day-month-year order rather than year-month-day order. Define a formatting pattern to match your string inputs. Use the modern class, `DateTimeFormatter`.

```
DateTimeFormatter f = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern( "dd/MM/uuuu" ) ;
```

Parse your input string.

```
LocalDate ld = LocalDate.parse( "31/10/2016" , f ) ;
```

> ld.toString(): 2018-10-31

Be clear that a date-time object has no “format”. Formats relate to text representing a date-time value/object, to the `String` object being generated from a date-time object. But the date-time object and the `String` remain separate and distinct.

By the way, do not use such a custom or localized format for your inputs. **Always use standard [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) formats** when exchanging date-time values as text. The *java.time* classes use these standard formats by default when parsing/generating strings.

## Define a class for data-model

Rather than mess with arrays or a bunch of `List` objects, define a class for your data. Name it something like `StockDay` to represent a stock’s performance on a particular date.

Never use `double` or `Double`, nor `float` or `Float`, to represent money. These types use [floating-point technology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating_Point) that trades away accuracy to get faster execution performance. Instead use the [`BigDecimal`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html) class; slower, but accurate.

On this class we include the business logic in defining a [Candlestick Hammer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hammer_(candlestick_pattern)). For simplicity, I went with the stricter definition disallowing an upper “shadow”. All this code is for demonstration-only, completely untested: Use at your own risk.

```
package com.basilbourque.example;

import java.math.BigDecimal;
import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.util.Objects;

public class StockDay implements Comparable < StockDay > {

    // Example data:
    // Date       Open  High  Low  Close
    // 31/10/2016 58.25 58.65 58.2 58.35

    // ---------|  Members  |------------------------
    private LocalDate date;
    private BigDecimal open, high, low, close;
    private Boolean isHammer;

    // ---------|  Constructors  |------------------------
    public StockDay ( final LocalDate localDateArg , final BigDecimal openArg , final BigDecimal highArg , final BigDecimal lowArg , final BigDecimal closeArg ) {
        // In real work, add defensive code to validate data such as no nulls, only positive numbers, reasonable dates.
        this.date = localDateArg;
        this.open = openArg;
        this.high = highArg;
        this.low = lowArg;
        // Verify the high is greater than or equal to the low.
        if ( this.high.compareTo( this.low ) < 0 ) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException( "The passed High is below the passed Low for Date of " + this.date + ". Not possible." );
        }
        this.close = closeArg;
        this.isHammer = this.determineHammer();
    }

    private Boolean determineHammer () {
        // A hammer is a price pattern in candlestick charting that occurs when a security trades significantly lower than its opening, but rallies later in the day to close either above or near its opening price. This pattern forms a hammer-shaped candlestick, in which the body is at least half the size of the tail or wick.
        // Read more: Hammer https://www.investopedia.com/terms/h/hammer.asp#ixzz5G6rqtbkv
        // See also: http://www.onlinetradingconcepts.com/TechnicalAnalysis/Candlesticks/Hammer.html

        // Caveat: This code is a quick rough draft, not thought-through, and totally untested. Use at your own risk. For demonstration purposes only.

        // First check if the High is above the Close. A Hammer has little or no upper  "shadow" (line protruding above the box). We'll go with "no shadow" for simplicity here.
        if ( this.high.compareTo( this.close ) > 0 ) { // if high > close, not a hammer.
            return Boolean.FALSE;
        }

        // Proceed with next check: Is "tail" (lower shadow) at least twice as long as height of box.
        BigDecimal closeOpenDeltaAbsolute_BoxHeight = this.close.subtract( this.open ).abs();
        BigDecimal lowerOfCloseOrOpen = ( this.close.compareTo( this.open ) < 0 ) ? this.close : this.open;  // If x is smaller than y, use x. If x is greater than or equal to y, use y.
        BigDecimal lowerShadowHeight = lowerOfCloseOrOpen.subtract( this.low );
        // A Hammer has a long lower shadow (delta between either Close or Open, whichever is lower, and the Low), at least twice as tall as the box (Close-Open absolute delta).
        BigDecimal requiredMinimumLengthFactorOfShadow = new BigDecimal( "2" );
        BigDecimal doubleCloseOpenDeltaAbsolute = closeOpenDeltaAbsolute_BoxHeight.multiply( requiredMinimumLengthFactorOfShadow );
        Boolean hammer = ( lowerShadowHeight.compareTo( doubleCloseOpenDeltaAbsolute ) > 0 );
        return hammer;

    }


    // ---------|  Accessors  |------------------------
    // All fields are read-only. Just getters, no setters.
    public LocalDate getDate () {
        return this.date;
    }

    public BigDecimal getOpen () {
        return this.open;
    }

    public BigDecimal getHigh () {
        return this.high;
    }

    public BigDecimal getLow () {
        return this.low;
    }

    public BigDecimal getClose () {
        return this.close;
    }

    public Boolean isHammer () {
        return this.isHammer;
    }

    // ---------|  Override `Object`  |------------------------
    @Override
    public String toString () {
        return "StockDay{ " +
                "date=" + this.date +
                ", open=" + this.open +
                ", high=" + this.high +
                ", low=" + this.low +
                ", close=" + this.close +
                ", isHammer=" + this.isHammer +
                " }";
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals ( final Object oArg ) {
        if ( this == oArg ) return true;
        if ( oArg == null || getClass() != oArg.getClass() ) return false;
        final StockDay stockDay = ( StockDay ) oArg;
        return Objects.equals( this.date , stockDay.date ) &&
                Objects.equals( this.open , stockDay.open ) &&
                Objects.equals( this.high , stockDay.high ) &&
                Objects.equals( this.low , stockDay.low ) &&
                Objects.equals( this.close , stockDay.close );
        // Perhaps this should be coded to only consider the `LocalDate` field alone.
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode () {
        return Objects.hash( this.date , this.open , this.high , this.low , this.close );
        // Perhaps this should be coded to only consider the `LocalDate` field alone.
    }


    @Override
    public int compareTo ( final StockDay o ) {
        // Compare the date field only.
        int result = this.getDate().compareTo( o.getDate() );
        return result;
    }
}
```

## Define a class for loading data

Create a class to load your CSV data.

```
package com.basilbourque.example;

import java.io.Reader;
import java.io.StringReader;
import java.math.BigDecimal;
import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;
import java.util.*;

public class StockDayLoader {
    final private DateTimeFormatter dateFormatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern( "dd/MM/uuuu" );  // Tip: Instead of this custom format, use standard ISO 8601 formats when exchanging date-time values as text.

    public List < StockDay > loadFrom ( final Reader input ) {
        final List < StockDay > stockDays = new ArrayList <>();  // To be populated by lines of data read from the input.

        try (  // try-with-resources
               Scanner scanner = new Scanner( input ).useDelimiter( "\r\n" ) ; // Delimiter is a comma between fields.
        ) {
            scanner.useLocale( Locale.US ); // Determines cultural norms such as FULL STOP versus COMMA for decimal point in a `BigDecimal`.

            // Skip first line, the column headers.
            if ( scanner.hasNextLine() ) {
                String headers = scanner.nextLine(); // Ignore returned String.
                if ( ! "Date,Open,High,Low,Close".equals( headers ) ) { // Verify expected input.
                    throw new IllegalArgumentException( "The passed Readable object’s first row does not consist of expected column header names." );
                }
            }

            while ( scanner.hasNextLine() ) {
                String line = scanner.nextLine(); // Grab entire line.
                try (
                        Scanner lineScanner = new Scanner( line ).useDelimiter( "," ).useLocale( Locale.US ) ;
                ) {
                    String dateInput = lineScanner.next();
                    LocalDate date = LocalDate.parse( dateInput , this.dateFormatter );
                    try {
                        BigDecimal open = lineScanner.nextBigDecimal();
                        BigDecimal high = lineScanner.nextBigDecimal();
                        BigDecimal low = lineScanner.nextBigDecimal();
                        BigDecimal close = lineScanner.nextBigDecimal();
                        StockDay stockDay = new StockDay( date , open , high , low , close );
                        stockDays.add( stockDay );  // Collect the newly intanstiated `StockDay` object.
                    } catch ( InputMismatchException e ) {
                        System.out.println( "ERROR The next token does not match the Decimal regular expression, or is out of range.  " );
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }

            return stockDays;
        }
    }


    // -----------|  Testing/Demo  |------------------------

    public static String bogusData () {
        final String eol = "\r\n";   // RFC 4180 requires CrLf as end-of-line.
        final StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        sb.append( "Date,Open,High,Low,Close" + eol );
        sb.append( "31/10/2016,58.25,58.65,58.2,58.35" + eol );
        sb.append( "28/10/2016,58.95,59,58.3,58.35" + eol );
        sb.append( "27/10/2016,58.78,58.22,33.3,58.55" + eol ); // Hammer.
        sb.append( "26/10/2016,58.95,59.05,58.43,58.45" + eol );
        sb.append( "25/10/2016,58.99,58.44,22.2,58.57" + eol ); // Hammer.
        String s = sb.toString();
        return s;
    }

    public static void main ( String[] args ) {
        String s = StockDayLoader.bogusData();
        Reader reader = new StringReader( s );

        StockDayLoader loader = new StockDayLoader();
        List < StockDay > list = loader.loadFrom( reader );

        System.out.println( list );
    }

}
```

### Apache Commons CSV

Even better, rather than write your own CSV reader, leverage existing well-used well-tested code found in a library such as [*Apache Commons CSV*](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-csv/).

```
package com.basilbourque.example;

import org.apache.commons.csv.CSVFormat;
import org.apache.commons.csv.CSVRecord;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.Reader;
import java.io.StringReader;
import java.math.BigDecimal;
import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class StockDayLoaderEasy {

    final private DateTimeFormatter dateFormatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern( "dd/MM/uuuu" );  // Tip: Instead of this custom format, use standard ISO 8601 formats when exchanging date-time values as text.

    public List < StockDay > loadFrom ( final Reader reader ) {
        final List < StockDay > stockDays = new ArrayList <>();  // To be populated by lines of data read from the input.

        Iterable < CSVRecord > records = null;
        try {
            records = CSVFormat.RFC4180.parse( reader );
        } catch ( IOException eArg ) {
            eArg.printStackTrace();
        }

        // Read each column. Names:  "Date,Open,High,Low,Close"
        for ( CSVRecord record : records ) {
            LocalDate date = LocalDate.parse( record.get( "Date" ) , this.dateFormatter );
            BigDecimal open = new BigDecimal( record.get( "Open" ) );
            BigDecimal high = new BigDecimal( record.get( "High" ) );
            BigDecimal low = new BigDecimal( record.get( "Low" ) );
            BigDecimal close = new BigDecimal( record.get( "Close" ) );

            StockDay stockDay = new StockDay( date , open , high , low , close );
            stockDays.add( stockDay );  // Collect the newly intanstiated `StockDay` object.
        }
        return stockDays;
    }

    // -----------|  Testing/Demo  |------------------------

    public static String bogusData () {
        final String eol = "\r\n";   // RFC 4180 requires CrLf as end-of-line.
        final StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        sb.append( "Date,Open,High,Low,Close" + eol );
        sb.append( "31/10/2016,58.25,58.65,58.2,58.35" + eol );
        sb.append( "28/10/2016,58.95,59,58.3,58.35" + eol );
        sb.append( "27/10/2016,58.78,58.22,33.3,58.55" + eol ); // Hammer.
        sb.append( "26/10/2016,58.95,59.05,58.43,58.45" + eol );
        sb.append( "25/10/2016,58.99,58.44,22.2,58.57" + eol ); // Hammer.
        String s = sb.toString();
        return s;
    }

    public static void main ( String[] args ) {
        String s = StockDayLoader.bogusData();
        Reader reader = new StringReader( s );

        StockDayLoader loader = new StockDayLoader();
        List < StockDay > list = loader.loadFrom( reader );

        System.out.println( list );
    }
}
```

## Pull it all together

Create an app to exercise these pieces.

The goal of the Question was to find which stock-day-reports met the criteria of (a) date within a date-range, AND (b) is a Hammer.

Several short examples are presented here. Some use old-fashioned Java syntax, and some use modern Streams/Lambda syntax, with same results either way. Read the code-comments for guidance.

```
package com.basilbourque.example;

import org.threeten.extra.LocalDateRange;

import java.io.Reader;
import java.io.StringReader;
import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Objects;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

public class HammerTime {
    public static void main ( String[] args ) {
        HammerTime hammerTime = new HammerTime();
        hammerTime.doIt();
    }

    private void doIt () {
        // Load all data.
        Reader reader = new StringReader( StockDayLoader.bogusData() );
        List < StockDay > stockDays = new StockDayLoader().loadFrom( reader );
        Collections.sort( stockDays );  // Sort chronologically, ascending order, oldest first. For newest first, call `Collections.reverse`.
        System.out.println( "All stockDays = " + stockDays );

        // Find hammers using the old-fashioned way.
        List < StockDay > hammers = new ArrayList <>();
        for ( StockDay stockDay : stockDays ) {
            if ( stockDay.isHammer() ) {
                hammers.add( stockDay );
            }
        }
        System.out.println( "hammers: " + hammers );

        // Find hammers using modern Streams/Lambda features, while tolerating NULLs.
        List < StockDay > hammers2 = stockDays.stream()
                .filter( stockDay -> Objects.equals( stockDay.isHammer() , Boolean.TRUE ) )  // Use `Objects.equals` to tolerate NULL values.
                .collect( Collectors.toList() );
        System.out.println( "hammers2: " + hammers2 );

        // Find hammers using modern Streams/Lambda features, assuming no NULL values exist.
        List < StockDay > hammers3 = stockDays.stream()
                .filter( stockDay -> stockDay.isHammer().equals( Boolean.TRUE ) )  // Simpler syntax than above, if you are certain of no NULLs.
                .collect( Collectors.toList() );
        System.out.println( "hammers3: " + hammers3 );

        // Find hammers within a certain date-range, per the original Question.

        // Parse the user’s input start/stop dates.
        LocalDate start = LocalDate.parse( "2016-10-26" ); // This range should pick up the hammer on the 27th while omitting the hammer on the 25th.
        LocalDate stop = LocalDate.parse( "2016-10-28" ); // Usual practice in defining a span-of-time is the Half-Open approach, where the beginning is *inclusive* while the ending is *exclusive*.

        // Find hammers within date range using the old-fashioned syntax, with built-in classes.
        List < StockDay > hammersInDateRange1 = new ArrayList <>();
        for ( StockDay stockDay : stockDays ) {
            if ( stockDay.isHammer() ) {
                if ( ( ! stockDay.getDate().isBefore( start ) ) && stockDay.getDate().isBefore( stop ) ) {
                    hammersInDateRange1.add( stockDay );
                }
            }
        }
        System.out.println( "hammersInDateRange1: " + hammersInDateRange1 );

        // Find hammers within date range using the old-fashioned syntax, with the ThreeTen-Extra library and its `LocalDateRange` class.  http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/
        final LocalDateRange dateRange = LocalDateRange.of( start , stop );
        List < StockDay > hammersInDateRange2 = new ArrayList <>();
        for ( StockDay stockDay : stockDays ) {
            if ( stockDay.isHammer() ) {
                if ( dateRange.contains( stockDay.getDate() ) ) {
                    hammersInDateRange2.add( stockDay );
                }
            }
        }
        System.out.println( "hammersInDateRange2: " + hammersInDateRange2 );

        // Find hammers within date range using modern Streams/Lambda syntax, with the ThreeTen-Extra library and its `LocalDateRange` class.  http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/
        List < StockDay > hammersInDateRange3 = stockDays.stream()
                .filter( stockDay -> stockDay.isHammer() && dateRange.contains( stockDay.getDate() ) )  // Assumes no NULLs.
                .collect( Collectors.toList() );
        System.out.println( "hammersInDateRange3: " + hammersInDateRange3 );


    }
}
```

When run.

> All stockDays = [StockDay{ date=2016-10-25, open=58.99, high=58.44, low=22.2, close=58.57, isHammer=true }, StockDay{ date=2016-10-26, open=58.95, high=59.05, low=58.43, close=58.45, isHammer=false }, StockDay{ date=2016-10-27, open=58.78, high=58.22, low=33.3, close=58.55, isHammer=true }, StockDay{ date=2016-10-28, open=58.95, high=59, low=58.3, close=58.35, isHammer=false }, StockDay{ date=2016-10-31, open=58.25, high=58.65, low=58.2, close=58.35, isHammer=false }]
>
> hammers: [StockDay{ date=2016-10-25, open=58.99, high=58.44, low=22.2, close=58.57, isHammer=true }, StockDay{ date=2016-10-27, open=58.78, high=58.22, low=33.3, close=58.55, isHammer=true }]
>
> hammers2: [StockDay{ date=2016-10-25, open=58.99, high=58.44, low=22.2, close=58.57, isHammer=true }, StockDay{ date=2016-10-27, open=58.78, high=58.22, low=33.3, close=58.55, isHammer=true }]
>
> hammers3: [StockDay{ date=2016-10-25, open=58.99, high=58.44, low=22.2, close=58.57, isHammer=true }, StockDay{ date=2016-10-27, open=58.78, high=58.22, low=33.3, close=58.55, isHammer=true }]
>
> hammersInDateRange1: [StockDay{ date=2016-10-27, open=58.78, high=58.22, low=33.3, close=58.55, isHammer=true }]
>
> hammersInDateRange2: [StockDay{ date=2016-10-27, open=58.78, high=58.22, low=33.3, close=58.55, isHammer=true }]
>
> hammersInDateRange3: [StockDay{ date=2016-10-27, open=58.78, high=58.22, low=33.3, close=58.55, isHammer=true }]

---

## About *java.time*

The [*java.time*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

The [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

To learn more, see the [*Oracle Tutorial*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

You may exchange *java.time* objects directly with your database. Use a [JDBC driver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC_driver) compliant with [JDBC 4.2](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/170) or later. No need for strings, no need for `java.sql.*` classes.

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), [**Java SE 10**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_10), and later

  - Built-in.
  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.
  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Much of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - Later versions of Android bundle implementations of the java.time classes.
  - For earlier Android (<26), the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) (mentioned above). See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

The [**ThreeTen-Extra**](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html), [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html), and [more](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/index.html).